# Is this method thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

Are  these methods `getNewId()` & `fetchIdsInReserve()` thread safe ?

```
public final class IdManager {

    private static final int NO_OF_USERIDS_TO_KEEP_IN_RESERVE = 200;

    private static final AtomicInteger regstrdUserIdsCount_Cached = new AtomicInteger(100);
    private static int noOfUserIdsInReserveCurrently = 0;

    public static int getNewId(){                   
          synchronized(IdManager.class){
              if (noOfUserIdsInReserveCurrently <= 20)
                      fetchIdsInReserve();    

              noOfUserIdsInReserveCurrently--;
          }
          return regstrdUserIdsCount_Cached.incrementAndGet();
    }


    private static synchronized void fetchIdsInReserve(){
        int reservedInDBTill = DBCountersReader.readCounterFromDB(....); // read column from DB 

        if (noOfUserIdsInReserveCurrently + regstrdUserIdsCount_Cached.get() != reservedInDBTill) throw new Exception("Unreserved ids alloted by app before reserving from DB");

        if (DBUpdater.incrementCounter(....)) //if write back to DB is successful
              noOfUserIdsInReserveCurrently += NO_OF_USERIDS_TO_KEEP_IN_RESERVE;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may still have a logic problem.  The first time `getNewId()` is called `noOfUserIdsInReserveCurrently = 0` so `fetchIdsInReserve()` is called and `noOfUserIdsInReserveCurrently = 199`.

Now imagine the thread gets parked before returning.

Now imagine this happens to 179 more threads.  So that we are now at `noOfUserIdsInReserveCurrently = 20` and triggering `fetchIdsInReserve()` again.  at this point there is no guarantee that `return regstrdUserIdsCount_Cached.incrementAndGet()` has ever been called so `regstrdUserIdsCount_Cached.get() = 0`.

Given this, does the check `if (noOfUserIdsInReserveCurrently + regstrdUserIdsCount_Cached.get() != reservedInDBTill)` fail?

This is not an issue if there are a fixed number of threads that can call this, like from a FixedThreadPool.  But if it is unconstrained then there might be a failure mode.

Comment: Thankyou so much! To solve this issue, should I include `regstrdUserIdsCount_Cached` inside the synchronized block & make it as a non final int instead of atomicInteger ?

Comment: To be honest I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish. But synchronizing the getNewId() method would make the whole system safe.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine this scenario: thread A arrives first and executes the entire `synchronized(IdManager.class)` block, but is interrupted before the row return `regstrdUserIdsCount_Cached.incrementAndGet();` so that the counter is not incremented.

The arrives thread B. It enters the `synchronized(IdManager.class)` block and gets the same Id as thread A!!!

This could happen because you have put the `regstrdUserIdsCount_Cached.incrementAndGet();` outside the syncronized block. If you put it inside, your code should be thread safe.

**UPDATE:**

The scenario described above is not possibile, because `incrementAndGet` is an atomic operation. Indeed, the code is thread-safe. My apologies.

Comment: Wanted to add that you might as well synchronize the method. When you synchronize(IdManager.class), you prevent any other thread from accessing any other synchronized static methods for that class.

Comment: I disagree with your reasoning, @vitalik. The decision on what ID to return to a thread is based solely on the result of `regstrdUserIdsCount_Cached.incrementAndGet()` - this is not influenced by the reservation logic, so the code is in fact threadsafe.

Comment: I guess you are right @sgmorrison. I corrected my answer.

Comment: @ApprenticeQueue:  In that case,  since I am calling a synchronized method(`fetchIdsInReserve()`) from a synchronized block that could lead to a deadlock, right?

Comment: @Raj no deadlock because Java uses reentrant synchronization; if you have the lock already, you don't need to acquire the same lock again.

Comment: @sgmorrison, that's not true. On vitalik's scenario, reservedInDBTill=100, noOfUserIdsInReserveCurrently=0, regstrdUserIdsCount_Cached=100. When thread A is interrupted, reservedInDBTill=300,  noOfUserIdsInReserveCurrently=199, and regstrdUserIdsCount_Cached=100. Let's say 179 threads has gone by (and thread A is still asleep) so now noOfUserIdsInReserveCurrently=20, regstrdUserIdsCount_Cached=279. When thread B comes in and calls fetchIdsInReserve(), 279+20 != 300 so exception will be thrown.

Comment: Good spot, @ApprenticeQueue. Will update my answer in due course.